# Can't turn FastCGI output buffering off

Tags: php, fastcgi

This script outputs after 10 seconds instead of incrementally:

```
ob_start(); // Start output buffer (if not enabled in php.ini)
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo $i, ' ';
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

I have IIS and FastCGI installed.  in PHP.ini, I have

```
zlib.output_compression = Off
output_buffering = off
```

In `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config` I have

```
<add name="PHP_viaFastCGI" 
path="*.php" 
verb="*" 
modules="FastCgiModule" 
scriptProcessor="C:\php\php-cgi.exe" 
resourceType="Unspecified" 
ResponseBufferLimit = "0"/>
```

All have seemingly no effect.

I need to find the correct way to turn off output buffering in FastCGI

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The solution is here: [PHP flush - User Contributed Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#113360)

> For a Windows system using IIS, the `responseBufferLimit` takes
> precedence over PHP's `output_buffering` settings. So you must also set
> the `responseBufferLimit` to be something lower than its default value.

In short, for IIS7+, edit the `%windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file and add `responseBufferLimit="0"` to the `PHP_via_FastCGI` handler.

So the entire line will look something like:

`<add name="PHP_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" responseBufferLimit="0" />`

After that, `ob_flush()` and `flush()` will start to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, also running FastCGI PHP, and got it fixed by putting the following line in my index file (from where all other files are included), before everything else:

```
while (@ob_end_flush());
```

I found this command in the [PHP docummentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php). .

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about IIS, but in CentOS I had to add the following to /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf:

```
OutputBufferSize 0
```

Found the answer here after searching for an hour: http://forum.odin.com/threads/mod_fcgid-php-flush-function.91876/